# Running cross-compiled qt application

Tags: qt, unicode, character-encoding, cross-compiling, iconv

I've got this qt app[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRPLp.png) that I've cross-compiled using cmake and openembedded.  It's cross-compiled from i686 to geode, so I figure I should be able to run it on the i686 host I compiled it on, if I link against the geode libraries.  As you can see from the image, it doesn't run quite right.  Using strace seems to indicate that qt is using some funny encoding for everything, e.g.:

```
stat64("\342\274\200\347\200\200\347\210\200\346\274\200\346\214\200", 0x869566c) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jayen

[image: qt app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that when I compiled qt, because I had already compiled libiconv, qt was using that, instead of gconv (iconv in glibc).  When I went to run it, it was using the cross-compiled libiconv, so I'm still not sure why it didn't work.

Wiping my cross-compile clean, and compiling qt without libiconv worked just fine.

I've since managed to get this running on a x86_64 host as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you cross-compile, it means you create a binary that will run on a different architecture from what you compiled it on.  In your case, this means you've used your i686 machine to build a binary that's supposed to run on geode architecture.  Your app is finding the Qt libraries on your computer and that is why it runs.  However, when Qt built your app, it converted some code to be geode specific, thus it's not "really" working.

If you tried this with a non-Qt app, you'd get an error when you tried to run this.

To test out your cross-compiled app, you'll have to run it inside Qemu that supports geode arch.  OpenEmebedded usually provides a Qemu target.  Check the available targets for geode, there should be one for Qemu.  Once you've done that, you can include your app to be part of the Qemu image that get's generated, or copy it over yourself into the Qemu image, and then you can run it.

Comment: :(  I'm doing all of this without root access, so qemu isn't an option for me.

Comment: You only need root if you're trying to use networking or need drivers for Qemu, otherwise, it will run just fine; a bit slow without the kvm drivers, but fine. Is there a reason why you need root?